# how to call a function in other component in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a board game, which uses a long code to generate data to the board.

Currently I have 2 components. Home and Board. Home only has a Welcome message and a button to navigate into Board.

Currently Board has the function to generate the data, but I'd like to move this function to other component, generate the data there and return an array to my Board component. This new function/component won't do anything else but return an array to Board.

Is it possible to do in React-Native? I'm coming from other programming logic, and I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: please show some demo code

Answer (score 0):

you can use props in React Native, [this link for documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props)  and [this for passing function in props to component](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the function component you can export you function like:

```
export const arrayFunction = () => {
// array generation code
   return array
}
```

and in your board component you can import the function from js file and use it like this.

```
const array = arrayFunction()
```

this constant array will have the array returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my best suggestion is that you need to use redux for the management of functions and states on several components and can be used anywhere (global) for the documentation, it can be seen clearly enough at:[Reudux Official](https://redux.js.org/)